# Printing Tabular data using bash to fit the screen width

Tags: bash, printf, tabular

I am printing the name of the files processed with my bash script. since there were many file paths being processed. I decided to make them be printed similar to `ls` command which prints tabular with respect to the width of the screen. But I dunno how many columns I can have in my screen and that can be totally different on monitor is there any automatic way to do it? or a simple function which would compute width and compare it to size of the strings...

```
printf "%s\t" "$FILENAME"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally this job is done using the `tput` program as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh

columns=$(tput cols)
lines=$(tput lines)

printf "terminal dimensions are: %sx%s\n" "$columns" "$lines"
```

To determine the number of characters in your strings do as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh

MYSTRING="This a long string containing 38 bytes"

printf "Length of string is %s\n" "${#MYSTRING}"
```

Taking advantage of the shell's ability to measure strings with `${#var}`.
Here is an example which puts these techniques together to format and center text:

```
#!/bin/sh

columns=$(tput cols)
lines=$(tput lines)
string="This text should be centered"
width="${#string}"
adjust=$(( (columns - width ) / 2))
longspace="                                             "

printf "%.*s" "$adjust" "$longspace"
printf "%s" "${string}"
printf "%.*s" "$adjust" "$longspace"
printf "\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

In Bash you can get the screen width and height from the `COLUMNS` and `LINES` builtin variables.
As described in another answer, you can get the length of a string in Bash by using `${#var}`.
You might find the ancient and venerable `pr` utility useful for generating output in columns.